# what is the command-line processing order for string operators like ${string#patten} in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I was learning the command-line processing of bash shell. I understand the process of substituting the value for a common parameter like `$para` or `${para}`. My question is what would be the processing order when string operator is involved. For example, if `para` is a variable preceded by a tab then followed by "string". It is known that `${para#\t}` is meant to delete the preceding tab in `para`. So how is this processed by the shell? Is there any command substitution involved?

Can anyone give any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: _Parameter expansion_ and _command substitution_ are two separate shell features.  One does not involve the other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the possibilities include. You can either expand-then-remove-the-tab, or remove-the-tab-then-expand, and the latter doesn't make much sense: what would you be removing the tab from?

Comment: Lacking any clarification from the OP, I am voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".